# Import raw file as a string

Tags: webpack

In a type script project, I have some raw text files I want to import as strings, and that should be bundled in the final js file.

I use Webpack 5.21 in my project.

Let's say I have somewhere in my source files :

- app.ts
- templates\index.ts
- templates\somefile.tmpl.html

I expect, from my app.ts file, to be able to import like this :

```
import {somefile } from './templates'
```

`somefile` should be a string that contains the raw content of the tmpl.html file.

Here's what I tried :

- in my webpack.config.ts file I added this rule :

  ```
        {
            test: /\.tmpl\.html$/i,
            type:'asset/source',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        }
  ```

I also added a resolve extension:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.tmpl.html'],
},
```

In my `templates\index.ts` file, I tried:

```
import somefile from './somefile.tmpl.html'

export default {
    somefile
}
```

However, when I call `webpack` from the command line I got:

```
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Code\myproject\src\templates\index.ts(4,23)
  TS2307: Cannot find module './somefile.tmpl.html' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

What's missing ?

PS: my background is a custom build system that took some typescript files, and convert them in standalone jsfiles. I'm not a running web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is related to Typescript, it doesn't recognize `.html` module

You need to add a `d.ts` file which will contain

```js
// global.d.ts
declare module '*.tmpl.html' {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  compiler: {
  ...
  },
  include: ["path/to/global.d.ts"]
}
```

Comment: can you clarify the last part ? what am I supposed to add in the tsconfig.json file ?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: it compiles now without error. However, in the ouputed javascript bundle, I don't get the string in the source

Comment: You probably need to apply raw-loader for these files

Comment: Raw-loader is deprecated according [the docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/)

Comment: my bad. A previous test broke the compilation. After fixed this, my setup includes as expected the strings in the outputed bundle.